# What's the common noun for "dareness"?

Tags: word-request

I think dareness is not the word, since it doesn't appear in [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/misspelling?term=dareness). What the common noun? Example sentence:

> The woman suddenly kissed the man. That put him into a __-induced
>   stupor.

Answer (score 4):

Daringness (or just daring) would be the noun forms you're looking for, but you might try "boldness" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Something is *daring* if it's boldly assertive in nature.  A person can be daring, and a person's actions can be described as daring, but you can't say "X is affected by something being boldly assertive" with anything derived from *dare*.

*By* might save the day here, and while *stupor induced by daring* will not work (because it's not clear *whose* daring), *stupor induced by her daring* would.  It will sound rather "deadpan" unless you can put an adjective in front of *stupor*:

> The woman suddenly kissed the man.  That put him into a swooning stupor induced by her daring.

This would sound better:

> The woman suddenly kissed the man, him then being induced to stupor by her daring.

Comment: In your last example it should be *he* and not *him*. Either way it's an awkward phrasing.

Comment: Is there a reason you stuck with the passive voice here? To me, "The woman suddenly kissed the man, her daring inducing him to stupor." sounds better than both.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear if you intent the woman's kiss to make the man stronger (daring) or weaker (stupor)?

But, the word you may be looking for is

> [embolden](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embolden)
>
> The woman's sudden kiss **emboldened** him to kiss her back.

Unless you do really mean

> stupor

in which case

> The woman's sudden kiss caused him to **melt** and become **weak-kneeded**.